# Apache Virtual Host Not Working

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm currently in the process of migrating several domains from Media Temple VPS to Linode VPS and all of the transfers have gone great until one of the last domains to move.

I've gone through the same process for this domain as all of the others, but when I try to access the domain, the server's default homepage is displayed rather than a test page I've created in the directory. When I run apache2ctl -D DUMP_VHOSTS, the domain shows as active and properly setup, so I feel like there's something that I'm missing.

I'm also not seeing any activity in the access log for this domain. I've not seen this issue before and any similar cases that have been solved aren't working for me

Comment: What IP address gets returned when you ping the domain (as in, old provider or new provider)? Have you tried pointing your hosts file over to it? Have you tried doing a propogation check using one of the results found on google?

Comment: What was the process you used to port the domains over?

Comment: Please sanitize (if nessecary) and post the contents of the vhost configuration file.